# Use Generic Supplier to throw unchecked excpetion

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have list of methods which has `Supplier<T>` arguments for returning default values of different types. However, in some cases I need to throw exception(unchecked) instead of values.

Currently, I have to pass the lambda for each function definition but I would like to create supplier instance for throwing the exception and re-use it in all function definition.

I have following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        testInt("Key1", 10, () -> 99);
        testInt("Key2", -19, () -> 0);
        testInt("Key3", null, () -> {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); //repetition
        });
        testBoolean("Key4", true, () -> Boolean.FALSE);
        testBoolean("Key5", null, () -> {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();//repetition
        });
    }

    static void testInt(String key, Integer value, Supplier<Integer> defaultValue)
    {
        if (value != null)
            System.out.printf("Key : %s, Value : %d" + key, value);
        else
            System.out.printf("Key : %s, Value : %d" + key, defaultValue.get());
    }

    static void testBoolean(String key, Boolean value, Supplier<Boolean> defaultValue)
    {
        if (value != null)
            System.out.printf("Key : %s, Value : %d" + key, value);
        else
            System.out.printf("Key : %s, Value : %d" + key, defaultValue.get());
    }
```

But I am looking to do something like :

```
final static Supplier<?> NO_VALUE_FOUND = () -> {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    };


testInt("Key3", null, NO_VALUE_FOUND);
testBoolean("Key5", null,NO_VALUE_FOUND);
```

Appreciate any help on this. 
Thanks.

Comment: And what is your question? What is wrong with `NO_VALUE_FOUND` solution?

Comment: @talex `testBoolean` for example in the last call, would require an argument of `Suuplier<Boolean>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to @jon-hanson's answer, you can define a method which returns the lambda directly, with no cast needed:

```
private <T> Supplier<T> noValueFound() {
    return () -> {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a method to convert the NO_VALUE_FOUND value to the appropriate type:

```
static <T>  Supplier<T> NO_VALUE_FOUND() {
    return (Supplier<T>) NO_VALUE_FOUND;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testInt("Key3", null, NO_VALUE_FOUND());
    testBoolean("Key5", null,NO_VALUE_FOUND());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better would be that you can use a more generic implementation like :

```
static <T> void test(String key, T value, Supplier<T> defaultValue) {
    if (value != null)
        System.out.println("Key : " + key + " Value " + value); // note the change from printf since that had type specific placeholders
    else
        System.out.println("Key : " + key + " Value " + defaultValue.get());
}
```

and further use it as :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("Key1", 10, () -> 99);
    test("Key2", -19, () -> 0);
    test("Key3", null, NO_VALUE_FOUND);
    test("Key4", true, () -> Boolean.FALSE);
    test("Key5", null, NO_VALUE_FOUND);
}
```

with `NO_VALUE_FOUND` as :

```
final static Supplier<?> NO_VALUE_FOUND = () -> {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
};
```

***Edit*** (from the comments):  If you try to pass your `NO_VALUE_FOUND` of type `Supplier<?>` to your test function, and pass anything other than the literal value `null` as the second argument, you will get a compiler error.

So in order to solve for cases where any other value other than null can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, use a generic implementation as [suggested in MikeFHay answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54037817/1746118)

Comment: your answer does not address OP's type-checking issue. If you try to pass your `NO_VALUE_FOUND` of type  `Supplier<?>` to your `test` function, and pass anything other than the literal value null as the second argument, you will get a compiler error.

Comment: @MikeFHay True, but what I understood from question was that it needed to return `NO_VALUE_FOUND ` for such null cases only.

Comment: If you know at writing-time that the second argument is null, you can just unconditionally call the supplier. This function is only useful if it can take a possibly-null variable as the second argument.